# Install turtlebot3

Tags: ros-kinetic, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hellow guys!!

I recived error install to Turtlebot3_simulations

```
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "gazebo_ros" with
  any of the following names:

    gazebo_rosConfig.cmake
    gazebo_ros-config.cmake
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288837/install-turtlebot3/) by [otluix](https://answers.ros.org/users/34675/otluix/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-04-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-04-16**:
Welcome! What command did you run to get this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you install the package you mentioned? If you want to install the package you mentioned, you can simply install it with the following command.

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-gazebo-ros
```

Also, when building packages from source, It is recommended to use the **rosdep** command. This command installs all the packages that the packages in your catkin workspace depend upon but are missing on your computer.

```
rosdep install --from-paths /path/to/your/catkin_ws/src --ignore-src -r -y
```

---

Originally posted by [Pyo](https://answers.ros.org/users/632/pyo/) with karma: 358 on 2018-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0